# Is SQL Server Spatial Index Rebuild Limited to Single-Threaded Execution

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, rebuild, spatial-index

When running Windows performance monitoring during a spatial index rebuild (using `MAXDOP=8`), it appears that there are two phases of the index rebuild process. The first phase (about 1/3 of the execution time) takes advantage of the `MAXDOP=8` during which there is a lot of read/write I/0. The second phase (about 2/3 of the execution), seems to be single-threaded even though `MAXDOP=8` is specified for the index rebuild command. Note that this is shown on SQL Server Enterprise (not Standard).

[image: Index Rebuild CPU Utilization]

Is this a limitation of spatial index rebuilds or all index rebuilds? If not, is there a way to force the entire rebuild to use more threads?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [ALTER INDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Important
>
> Although the MAXDOP option is syntactically supported for all XML indexes, **for a spatial index** or a primary XML index, **ALTER INDEX currently uses only a single processor.**

Comment: Thanks, Lukasz. However, I've tested many different MAXDOP values and seen them used for that first phase of the rebuild process. Do you think the documentation you referenced is simply stating that only a single processor can be used for simplicity even though it seems you can take advantage of multiple for the first phase? If so, do you know of any documentation that describes the rebuild phases that would explain this further